# Getting Laravel Workbench Package Config Values From Within ServiceProvider Registration

Tags: laravel

Within MymoduleServiceProvider->register(),
I want to be able to pull configuration values from the same package.

However whenever I

```
var_dump($app['config']['file.option']
```

I get a null value

I know that the file structure is correct because if I do:

```
Config::get('package::file.option');
```

from a controller, I get the correct value

How can I load my packages configuration values from within the ServiceProvider->register() method?

Comment: did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$app['config']` is an instance of `Config` stored in the IOC container.

---

So try using the `get()` method directly from the IOC container like so:

```
$app['config']->get('package::file.option');
```

as an equivalent to using the facade

```
\Config::get('package::file.option');
```

Comment: Brian, will test tonight. Thanks